# How to get smooth edges with png image in tkinter label

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, png

When I place a png image with transparent background as a label on a tkinter canvas, the edges are rippled. How could I get smooth edges? See two examples:

[image]

and

[image]

I have the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk # Python 3
master = tk.Tk()
master.minsize(500, 500)
master.geometry("500x500")
master.overrideredirect(True)
master.lift()
master.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
master.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "white")
master.configure(background='white')

img = tk.PhotoImage(file="c:/temp/co.png")
panel = tk.Label(master, image = img, text="2", bg="white", compound=tk.CENTER, fg="#EFEFEF", font=("Helvetica", 14))
panel.place(x=300, y=200)

tk.mainloop()
```

The idea is to have a transparent layer on top of the windows desktop on which widgets containing a png image are placed.

**EDIT:**
The answer by Aivaras Kazakevičius below resulted in:

[image]  [image: Enlarged]

The original image to play around with is:
[image]

Comment: You need to modify the image to change the pixels around the circle to white color.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But that's not the right solution. The pixels around the circle are semi-transparent resulting in the smooth edge. Replacing these bij just white makes the circle even more granular.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT #1

I have confirmed that the problem arises because of premultiplication of images. Originally I thought that the white border around the transparent image is drawn because of how the image is loaded by PIL. I played around with it and found that PIL handles alphas and RGB values just fine.

After inspecting the code I noticed one thing I didn't like in line:

```
panel = tk.Label(master, image=ph, text="2", bg="white", compound=tk.CENTER, fg="#EFEFEF", font=("Helvetica", 14))
```

The `bg="white"` part was the bit that I had problems with since I was sure that the source of tcl/tk interferes with RGB values of the transparent bits of the image. Now, I wasn't able to get to the tcl/tk source code because I don't know how to access it (sorry, still a newbie to programming). But my guess was, that what the referenced line of code does with the picture is this: it takes the default or set by the user `bg` values ant splashes it on our transparent image making the whole transparency thing effectively useless. What should we do then? Well, we have to prepare the image for this procedure - do the premultiplication. The edited code is posted below. Below i post examples of what i have got:

[image]

[image]

The images still look a little pixelated. I believe reading more about premultiplication and finding tcl/tk source that handles the setting of background would allow to choose better parameters for premultiplication. Alternatively you could try to combine your image with a white background manually and experiment with different ways to do the premultiplication.

Some references:

The reason for the problem is described quite well here (check out comments for more usefull info): https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200801/truly_transparent_text_with_pil.html

There is also a good explanation about premultiplication here:
http://www.spherevfx.com/written-training/miscellaneous-written-training/understanding-premultiplied-images/

Hope this helps you:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

master = tk.Tk()
master.geometry("500x500")
master.attributes("-topmost", True)
master.configure(background='white')
master.attributes("-transparentcolor", "white")

im = Image.open('A.tif')
width, height = im.size
px = im.load()
for i in range(width):
    for j in range(height):
        if px[i, j][3] != 0 and px[i, j][3] != 255:
            R = int(round(px[i, j][1] * px[i, j][3]))
            G = int(round(px[i, j][1] * px[i, j][3]))
            B = int(round(px[i, j][1] * px[i, j][3]))
            a = px[i, j][3]

            px[i, j] = (R, G, B, a)
            print(px[i, j])


ph = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
panel = tk.Label(master, image=ph, text="2", bg="white", compound=tk.CENTER,
                 fg="#EFEFEF", font=("Helvetica", 14))
panel.pack()
panel.image = ph  # image reference

tk.mainloop()
```

Side note: wm_attributes() does exactly the same as attributes() - I prefer to use the later for less typing.

RESULT:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this does not work. Still gives the granular edges. See image in Edit of the question.

Comment: Maybe you could post your original image to play around with?

Comment: Hi Aivaras, the original image has been added.

Comment: Hey Bill, so I've worked on this problem for 2 hours now and finally got the solution. I turns out it is an issue with premultiplication, just in a different way. I'll edit my answer ASAP.

Comment: Hi Aivaras, I have added the resulting image which is more or less a bitmap type image. So this approach does not really work unfortunately. But thanks for your ideas and efforts anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a new image is created. The "white" colors in the resulting image are no longer true white, e.g. (255,255,223) instead of (255,255,255). As a result the transparant mask does not cover these pixels and remain visible.

If you have a fixed color background, the easiest solution is to create an icon that does not have a white transparant, but already has the same background color. You might set this to the transparant color as well.
If this is not the case, then you can consider a neutral background color instead of white and use it as the transparant color.